# Application cannot not be deployed in Tomcat 8 due to StackOverflowError

Tags: web-deployment, tomcat8

I m trying to deploy a WAR application on my server using Tomcat 8.

I put the WAR file in the `webapps` directory, modified the `server.xml` but I can't access the application.

I connect to the Tomcat manager and I can see my application but when I try to start it I got the message

> FAIL - Application at context path /bo could not be started

In the Tomcat logs there's the following error:

> 28-Apr-2016 10:16:01.060 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-3] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup Servlet [cxf] in web application [/bo] threw load() exce$
>    java.lang.StackOverflowError

Can you help me?

Comment: Please add the stack trace

Comment: @MarkThomas sorry for the late here is the stack trace 
` com.utils.TechnicalException: javax.naming.NamingException:
 Cannot create resource instance
 Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance`